# Searching name of a desgin concept

Tags: javascript, css, html

I‘m looking for **the name of the design concept** of blocks in plaintext that have can be edited or open a context menu while the rest of the text is static and not changeable. 
An example would be a configuration window with lines like: "After 5 Minutes the system will go into energy saving mode". 
Her the 5 Minutes would have a border and is clickable to enter a different number or change the the time unit. Beside that it appears as one solid text and not a text with a input box followed by more text.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: *cloze text* maybe?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between "has a border" and "an input box"?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with `contentEditable` attribute

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<span>After <span class="bold" contentEditable>5 Minutes</span> the system will go into energy saving mode</span>
```

Comment: Thanks that is somehting like im looking for but the more importnat thing is what the name of this desgin concept is

Comment: im not sure, maybe inline edit?